# The program is not executed - compilation warnings

Tags: java, serialversionuid

I am a new java programmer. I am trying to execute this program in eclipse but the error is

```
The serializable class LoveJava does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long.
```

---

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Why I have to declare this line?

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

public class LoveJava extends GraphicsProgram {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void run(){
        add(new GLabel("I love Java"),100,75);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that an error or warning ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html - The best explanation you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to java community.

Read [specific API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)  before asking here and here is the essential part of API.

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:

Comment: +1 for bringing the best explanation - The original one.

Answer (score 0):

Read blog post ["Eclipse: Ignore “Not Declare Static Final SerialVersionUID” Warning"](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/eclipse-ignore-serialversionuid-warning/) in order to configure Eclipse to ignore this compiler warning.

Or add `@SuppressWarnings(“serial”)` right before your class declaration to avoid the compiler warning from being raised in the first place. Like this:

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

@SuppressWarnings(“serial”)
public class LoveJava extends GraphicsProgram {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void run(){
        add(new GLabel("I love Java"),100,75);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.